# How to change default region in Google Cloud Console?

Tags: firebase, gcc, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, scheduler

I'm trying to change default region for cloud functions.
Client side I've changed like this:

```
const firebaseFunctions = require("firebase-functions");
const functions = firebaseFunctions.region("europe-west3");
```

And now when I deploy I can see the correct region.
But when I go to the logs in Google Cloud I see 2 hours less so the scheduler doesn't trigger my function.

In the documentation I read that you can get and change the default region from Google Cloud Console. This is my console:

```
****@cloudshell:~ (*****)$ gcloud config set functions/region europe-west3
Updated property [functions/region].
****@cloudshell:~ (project)$ gcloud config get-value compute/region
Your active configuration is: [cloudshell-*****]
europe-west3
```

Could be a propagation problem? Or am I missing something?

[EDIT]
The function triggers like this:

```
functions.pubsub.schedule('0 6 * * *').onRun(async (context) => {
...
}
```

What I expect: function is triggered at 6:00 AM

Answer (score 1):

[SOLVED]
The default region was already changed, but the region of my function in Cloud Scheduler was not. To change it:

1. Go to Firebase-> Functions
2. Open options for your function and press "Open in Cloud Scheduler"
3. In Cloud Scheduler select your function and press "Edit"
4. Choose the timezone you prefer

Maybe is not the best practice, but it works. If you know a better way to do it please leave answer

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain|show your issue with Cloud Logging?

You are correct that you can select the region for the Firebase function using `.region("europe-west3")`. This will deploy the function to that region.

However, `gcloud` is a separate command and using `gcloud config` **only** applies to subsequent `gcloud` commands; you're not using `gcloud` and so won't be affected by that change.

Comment: My issue is that my function isn't triggered at the correct time (europe-west3 time).
I think that's becouse the server has another region, in fact logs show 2 hours less than my time zone. Or am I wrong?

"However, gcloud is a separate command and using gcloud config only applies to subsequent gcloud commands; you're not using gcloud and so won't be affected by that change." 
What do you mean with this? Sorry but I'm new with GC

Comment: What triggers your function? Are you able to include details in your question. I wonder whether perhaps the logs are showing UTC vs. Frankfurt time?

Comment: It's confusing. Google Cloud Platform (GCP) hosts Firebase. Both are Google but Firebase is an acquisition. Firebase Functions are GCP Cloud Functions but there are 2 sets of tools to interact with these overlapping services. For GCP, `gcloud` is the CLI (it is part of [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk)) but Firebase has its own CLI called [`firebase`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli). Using `gcloud set config` won't change `firebase` settings. But, more importantly, neither affects Cloud Logging.

Comment: I've updated with the function trigger.

Comment: Thanks! I'm unclear when (if ever) the function is triggered. You say "2 hours less" which is unclear to me. You're not setting a time zone `functions.pubsub.schedule(...).timeZone(...).onRun(...)` and so the default will be used. You should likely specify CET.

Comment: functions is declared like this
`
const firebaseFunctions = require("firebase-functions");
const functions = firebaseFunctions.region("europe-west3");
`